# Ошибка драйвера mysql при переходе на php7

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

В результате перехода на Bitrix 16.5 и php версии 7 получил следующую багу:

```
File: bitrix/modules/sale/mysql/delivery.php
```

Line: 174

```
MySQL Query Error: SELECT DISTINCT D.ID as ID, D.NAME as NAME, D.LID as LID,
D.PERIOD_FROM as PERIOD_FROM, D.PERIOD_TO as PERIOD_TO, 
D.PERIOD_TYPE as PERIOD_TYPE, D.WEIGHT_FROM as WEIGHT_FROM,
D.WEIGHT_TO as WEIGHT_TO, D.ORDER_PRICE_FROM as ORDER_PRICE_FROM,
D.ORDER_PRICE_TO as ORDER_PRICE_TO, D.ORDER_CURRENCY as ORDER_CURRENCY,
D.ACTIVE as ACTIVE, D.PRICE as PRICE, D.CURRENCY as CURRENCY,
D.SORT as SORT, D.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION, D.LOGOTIP as LOGOTIP,
D.STORE as STORE FROM b_sale_delivery D WHERE ((((D.LID = 's1' ))))
AND ((((D.WEIGHT_FROM <= 942 )) OR (D.WEIGHT_FROM IS NULL) OR
(D.WEIGHT_FROM = 0))) AND ((((D.WEIGHT_TO >= 942 )) OR 
(D.WEIGHT_TO IS NULL) OR (D.WEIGHT_TO = 0))) AND ((() OR 
(D.ORDER_PRICE_FROM IS NULL) OR (D.ORDER_PRICE_FROM = 0))) 
AND ((() OR (D.ORDER_PRICE_TO IS NULL) OR (D.ORDER_PRICE_TO = 0)))
AND ((((D.ACTIVE = 'Y' )))) AND ((())) ORDER BY D.SORT ASC,
D.NAME ASC 
    [[1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
    version for the right syntax to use near ')
    OR (D.ORDER_PRICE_FROM IS NULL)
 OR (D.ORDER_PRICE_FROM = 0))) AND ((() OR (D.O' at line 1]
```

Пытаюсь понять суть ошибки. Предполагаю, что она возникла ввиду перехода на другой драйвер и структура запроса несколько поменялась. Хотелось бы знать, куда копать.

Comment: `((() OR (D.ORDER_PRICE_FROM IS NULL)` - пустые скобки видите? Пустыми быть не должны, это и есть синтаксическая ошибка. Напрямую с версией PHP не связано, неверно формируется сам запрос. Ищите, где он формируется и почему внутри скобок пусто.